# Facebook Connect is not working properly, showing call back URL in same popup

Tags: facebook, popup

I have used Facebook Connect in my site but it is not working properly. When I click on the Facebook Connect button it shows a popup after that when I enter my login and password it shows the callback URL in the same popup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens when facebook is not able to find the `xd_receiver` file, make sure that you have specified that one correctly.

To make the things easy, you can use the:

**[Facebook Connect Wizard](http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/310)**

to create facebook connect easily.

Answer (score 0):

It was temporarily down for several hours yesterday but it is fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

Try firefox (a browser other than IE).

I have faced same problem with IE sometimes, when it was working in firefox.

At least, that tells you you are not doing things totally wrong.